# Low-level detail of char representation on a computer

Tags: c, ascii

I read that in C, char is actually an integer because characters are represented as patterns of bits.

So I wonder when you run your program how does the operating system know when to print the bits pattern as a number or a char. What code does determine which is to be printed?

And, where is the ASCII table located, and how does the conversion work?

Comment: There's an ASCII table on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_printable_characters)...

Comment: I think you're confused between C, which is an abstract programming *language*, and *hardware*, which is expensive metal that melts if you don't cool it. The former is used to *program* the latter, but that doesn't mean that C literally describes a processor.

Comment: Yes I might be confused. but I know that both are different things.

Comment: I meant where in the OS is the ASCII Table located? the one the OS uses to make the conversions

Comment: It might be educational if you learn about "type systems" and what they're for.

Comment: Everything to a computer is a number.  What that number means is defined (almost exclusively these days) by software.  In C, a "char" is a 1 byte signed number.  How you use this number (i.e. `printf("%c", chr)`) is up to you.  Note: C defines `sizeof(char)==1` which is typically 8 bits but doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 4):

> How does the operating system know when to print the bits pattern as a number or a char.

It doesn't. You explicitly tell the compiler whether to treat it as a character or integer by specifying the proper ***[format descriptor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)*** to `printf`. And that is the very reason that if there is a mismatch between format descriptor and type of the actual argument then it results in Undefined Behavior.

Comment: In case you're curious about how C++ differentiates when using `cout`, the compiler searches for the overload of `ostream`'s `<<` operator, which does different things based on the input type.

Comment: Okay but what part of the operating system actually prints?

Comment: Depends on operating system.  Some OSs have specific libraries for printing text to screen.  You can see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminals for more information.

Comment: @Als what happens when the program asks the user for input, how then does it distinguish? still with format descriptor?

Comment: @Apeee: Yes.`scanf()` operates on the basis of format descriptors.

Comment: @Als So, in run-time, it has to reserve memory for the input and in it to state what it asks for? (int/char)

Comment: @Apeee: `scanf` is a dumb function.It does not understand memory requirements and how to read and and so on.You need to teach it to read data correctly. `scanf` does not reserve memory,it simply reads contents in to address you pass to it as parameters.It is your responsibility to make sure the address pass is valid and memory allocated is sufficient to hold the read data. And how to treat the read data is dictated by format desciptor you specify.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you tell your program to interpret the bits in your code. For example,

`printf("%d %c", 'a', 97);`

This will print: `97 a`

Comment: I understand but is there a part of the OS that actually prints the char/number? or is it in the hardware?

Comment: @Apeee It can be in either or both. Text modes of CGA/EGA/(S)VGA displays operate with ASCII codes and characters are visualized using hardware or programmable fonts (character depictions, basically). In graphics modes, it's usually the task of the OS to draw characters using the same font idea.

Comment: Thank you alex, this is part of what I wanted to understand but found not the words to describe it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running a linux machine just type man ascii in a terminal and you'll see all of the char values (in decimal, octal and hexa). If not, just google ascii table and you'll probably be done.

Comment: Neat, didn't know Linux had a built in ASCII table

Comment: I don't use it. But there are many tables on the internet for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> ... characters are represented as patterns of bits.

On a computer, *everything* is represented as a pattern of bits: characters, integers, real numbers, and executable code. The eight bits `01000001` could represent the integer `65` (though integers normally take up at least 16 bits), or the letter `A` in the ASCII system. There are elaborate ways of keeping track of what is what, it's one of the main responsibilities of the operating system and of high-level programming languages. `printf` is one of the rare cases where the programmer has to explicitly *tell* a function what kind of data is being passed.

> I read that in C, char is actually an integer because characters are represented as patterns of bits.

That's not quite right: In C, chars and ints have been distinct types for a very long time. C allows you to use a `char` as an `int` if you want, by choice of the language designers: the bit pattern is basically used as the corresponding `int`. C won't let you use a `float` as an `int` since the bit pattern would not give you anything useful (the bit pattern for `1.0` looks nothing like the bit pattern for integer `1`).

As for the ASCII table, it's embodied in the design of the hardware and software that displays text, and of the programming language functions that manipulate it. A computer *font* is a mapping from numbers to shapes. or "glyphs". In the simplest case, it maps numbers in the ASCII range (32-126) to the appropriate glyph. (In reality it's often a more indirect route to the same result). Old computer terminals had the glyphs hardwired, while Windows or X11 applications use software fonts.

As for programming languages, a function like `isdigit()` or `isalpha()` just looks up the character code on a table of its properties: `isdigit()` returns `true` for the numbers 48-57 (which encode the ASCII digits), and `false` for all others. No glyphs are involved.